# Downloading solana CLI failing

Tags: solana-cli

Currently we run  `sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.solana.com/v1.14.11/install)"` in github actions to download the solana CLI as part of continuous integration testing. However lately we've getting more and more failures. Even with adding retries and long waiting times between retries, it still fails very frequently with the following error:

```
downloading v1.14.11 installer
Error: error decoding response body: invalid type: map, expected a sequence at line 1 column 0
```

Any ideas what could be causing the download to fail or what we could do to fix it?

Is solana rate limiting us or something?

Answer (score 0):

This is usually related to serialziation or some json related mapping.

Retrying should solve your problem,

Comment: Like i said, the command retry a lot, up to 10 times with 5 minutes between the tries and it still fails. It's also a new thing that's only started happening recently and has been getting worse. It's seemingly random as well.

Comment: @HenryE let's get a GitHub issue to triage this

Comment: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/19735 Someone opened something similar here but i didn't know if it was appropriate for github issue. I added something to the issue there anyway